# Is there any api to create voicemails for android

Tags: android, flutter

How to use android telephony API under which I want to use voicemail service API for using it for making a visual voice mail app. I want to set up a voicemail greeting through my custom app

Answer (score 1):

Not for what you want.  There's ways to programatically access voicemails that have been downloaded to your device.  But there's no API to change your voicemail greeting, that's all handled by individual carriers.  The API for the accessing voicemails is https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/VoicemailContract